# Play music from URI

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating a simple music player in which user can add songs to the list in my app. Then when the user taps on a song item in the list, the user is given an option to play songs using the music players available on their device.

This is how i'm getting uri of a particular song:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("audio/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Music File"), 200);

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
        if (resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            if (reqCode == 200) {
                Uri audioFileUri = data.getData();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), audioFileUri.getPath().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                play(audioFileUri);

            }
        }
   }
```

And this is how i'm playing the song:

```
public void play(Uri uri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The music player crashes or reports that it can't play the particular file.
The uri i'm getting is: "/document/primary:abc.mp3"

Comment: Just because you have rights to work with the chosen content does not mean that another app has rights to work with the chosen content.

Comment: There must be some way to implement it as many apps have done that before. Please give some solution.

Comment: "There must be some way to implement it as many apps have done that before" -- name any. File managers directly browse the filesystem. Other apps use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to get the `Uri`, then copy the content into their own app; those could play back their own copy.

Comment: "/storage/emulated/0/abc.mp3" when i pass this uri directly to the app, the song does play in the music player of my choice.

Comment: In the above comment, i meant the path and not the uri as such.